# Reset rotation direction of mirrored object

Tags: animation, transforms, mirror

I need help regards of reseting rotation of mirrored object.

I duplicated eye object of my character and wanna to rotate them (both eyes) via action.
I wanna use one action for both eyes, but: eyes are rotating in different direction even if the values of axes is the same.

Please for one quick kick.

Thanks a lot.

Updated with screenshots

Left and right eye rotated by 40 degrees Z-axis (same value but different direction)
[image: 40 degrees Z-axis]

This is what I expect
[image: This is what I expect]

Comment: How did you duplicate those eyes objects (via Mirror modifier ? if yes, did you apply it ?) and what kind of "action" do you use to rotate ?

Comment: I just duplicated the object, mirrored - no modifier, and applied transformations to reset axes.

Comment: Do you mean [rotating objects individually](http://i.imgur.com/lrCc8en.gif) ? It depends on pivot point then. Not sure what was meant to be "reset rotation" though.

Comment: see updated with screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so we have a scene with a pair of mirrored objects. I am using arrows because they have a clearer direction than spheres.

[image]

Supposing that they are created with a mirror modifier, you will have something like this in your modifiers panel:

[image]

Now, if you rotate the eyes in edit mode, you get this:

[image: image description]

To spin the eyes differently, you will have to separate them from each other. This is a destructive operation.

(Personally, I would first back them up to another layer. To do that, duplicate (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>), then cancel the grab (right click). Then move the copied object to another layer with <kbd>m</kbd>.)

Apply the mirror modifier by hitting apply here:

[image]

Then, in edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) hit <kbd>P</kbd> and select `By loose parts`. Now you have two objects, but their centers are off:

[image]

Select one of the eyes and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and select `Origin to Geometry`.

Now you can happily rotate the eyes independently. To make the eyes move in synch, go to constraints:

[image]

There, `Add Object Constraint` > `Copy Rotation` (second row, second collumn). Then pick the other eye as `Target`:

[image]

Now the objects rotate in synch:

[image: image description]

You can also make it so that the eyes look at a point in space. First, add an empty to be that point (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > `Empty` > pick any you want.) Put it where the eyes look. With one eye selected go in `Constraints` and add `Track To`. Select the empty as the `Target`. If the eye points the wrong way, play around with the `To:` and `Up:` parameters until it works. Repeat for the other eye. Here is the result:

[image: image description]

I hope this helps.